# Error in running spring boot application connected to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

Once I run my code it gives below error. How[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/br1Xd.png) I can solve it.

Field personRepository in com.example.demo.service.PersonService required a bean named 'mongoTemplate' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'mongoTemplate' in your configuration.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask good questions. Please use proper formatting. Please provide the code that causes the exception. Please provide the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly register bean to spring container.

```
    @Configuration public class AppConfig {

          public @Bean MongoClient mongoClient() {
              return new MongoClient("localhost");   }

          public @Bean MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
              return new MongoTemplate(mongoClient(), "mydatabase");   
} }
```